# SQLite - First Per Group - Composite Order & Opposing Sort Order

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I'm looking for options on how to pick the first record per group, in SQLite, Where the sorting of the group is across a composite key.

Example Table:

```
 Key_1 | Sort1 | Sort2 | Val_1 | Val_2
-------+-------+-------+-------+------- 
   1   |   1   |   3   |   0   |   2
   1   |   1   |   2   |   2   |   4
   1   |   1   |   1   |   4   |   6
   1   |   2   |   2   |   6   |   8
   1   |   2   |   1   |   8   |   1
   2   |   1   |   2   |   0   |   5
   2   |   1   |   1   |   1   |   6
   2   |   2   |   3   |   2   |   7
   2   |   2   |   2   |   3   |   8
   2   |   2   |   1   |   4   |   9
```

Objective:
- Sort data by `Key_1 ASC, Sort1 ASC, Sort2 DESC`
- Select first record per unique `Key_1`

```
 Key_1 | Sort1 | Sort2 | Val_1 | Val_2
-------+-------+-------+-------+------- 
   1   |   1   |   3   |   0   |   2
   2   |   1   |   2   |   0   |   5
```

Analytic Function Solution...

```
 SELECT
    *
 FROM
 (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key_1
                               ORDER BY Sort1,
                                        Sort2 DESC
                          )
                              AS group_ordinal
    FROM
        table
 )
     sorted
 WHERE
     group_ordinal = 1
```

Laborious ANSI-92 approach...

```
SELECT
    table.*
FROM
    table
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        table.Key1, table.Sort1, MAX(table.Sort2) AS Sort2
    FROM
        table
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Key_1, MIN(Sort1)
        FROM
            table
        GROUP BY
            Key_1
    )
        first_Sort1
            ON  table.Key_1 = first_Sort1.Key_1
            AND table.Sort1 = first_Sort1.Sort1
    GROUP BY
        table.Key1, table.Sort1
)
    first_Sort1_last_Sort2
        ON  table.Key_1 = first_Sort1_last_Sort2.Key_1
        AND table.Sort1 = first_Sort1_last_Sort2.Sort1
        AND table.Sort2 = first_Sort1_last_Sort2.Sort2
```

This involves a lot of nesting and self joins.  Which is cumbersome enough when it involves just two sort columns.

My actual example has **six** sort columns.

I also would like to avoid anything like the following, as it is ***not*** *(to my knowledge)* guaranteed / deterministic...

```
SELECT
    table.*
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    table.Key_1
ORDER BY
    MIN(table.Sort1),
    MAX(table.Sort2)
```

Are there any other options that I'm just not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work in SQLite:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from (select t2.*
                    from table t2
                    where t2.id = t.id
                    order by t2.sort1 asc, t2.sort2 desc
                    limit 1
                   ) t2
              where t2.sort1 = t.sort1 and t2.sort2 = t.sort2
             );
```

My concern is whether SQLite allows correlated references in nested subqueries.  If not, you can just use `=` and concatenate the values together:

```
select t.*
from table t
where (sort1 || ':' || sort2) =
          (select (sort1 || ':' || sort2)
           from table t2
           where t2.id = t.id
           order by sort1 asc, sort2 desc
           limit 1
          );
```

Comment: Nice, both queries giving `WHERE (a,b) = (SELECT a,b FROM x)`, but being SQLite compatible.  I'll give them both a go, then strain my brain on which option is the least obfuscated *(for whatever poor dev has to deal with it is a year's time)*.

Comment: @MatBailie . . . Although I'm not thrilled with the second solution, it is probably clearer to someone who is reading the query for the first time.

Comment: went with the first one to avoid problems with implicit type conversions.  Then added judicious comments about the correlation and the order by being similar to partitions and order by in analytic functions.  Did fund one interesting limitation.  The outer query's fields can be referenced in the WHERE clause, but not the ORDER BY.  Not sure if that means this is unsupported functionality.  Will dig deeper another day.